# flask-sqlalchemy cannot add/query data to database properly

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I cannot seem to add new data to the database **with a proper id**, if I do `User.query.all()` after add and commit data, it will return me `[None]`, and if I print out stuff in the database, it will give me `(None, username1, password1, email1, image_file1)` where the `None` is supposed to be the user_id.

my code for user model:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    def get_id(self):
           return (self.user_id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.user_id}', '{self.username}', '{self.email}')"
```

my code for adding data:

```
user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

and the db here is an AWS RDS:

```
db_url = 'mysql+mysqldb://' + user + ':' + passw + '@' + host + ':3306/' + database

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db_url

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

there are two tables in the database called 'user' and 'news'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign a value to the user_id. You can fix this either by autoincrement the `user_id`, i.e. change the definition of user_id to:

```py
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, auto_increment=True)
```

Or you can assign a specific value when adding the row:

```py
user = User(user_id=1, username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
```

I would prefer the first option if you don't have a good reason to assign the user_id manually.